# Load XML to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, xml

I need some input on how to best load the below XML file to MySQL.

I have a XML file which contains info like below:

```
<Start><Account>0001</Account><Asset>ABC</Asset><Value>500</Value><Asset>DEF</Asset><Value>600</Value></Start>
<Start>.......
```

When I use

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'file.xml' INTO TABLE my_tablename ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Start>
```

the file loads successfully but the account column is all NULL.

```
I.e., select * from my_tablename;
Account | Asset | Value
Null    | ABC   | 500
Null    | DEF   | 600
```

as opposed to

```
I.e., select * from my_tablename;
Account | Asset | Value
0001    | ABC   | 500
0001    | DEF   | 600
```

What's the best way to handle this? re-format the file in python first? Another SQL query?

Thank you.

Comment: I dont know if it Linked but you have only one account attribut for 2 rows

Comment: If assets ABC and DEF both belong to account 0001, the usual way to express that in XML is to have the `<Account>` tag enclose both of the assets.

Comment: I agree, the problem seems to be with the XML.

Comment: Python's [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module can transform XML files using XSLT, the special purpose language designed to do just this.

Answer (score 0):

To have the result you need, your XML should be like this:

```
<Start><account>0001</account><asset>ABC</asset><value>500</value></Start>
<Start><account>0001</account><asset>DEF</asset><value>600</value></Start>
```

One account, asset and value tag per Start tag.